# How to build Android code from GitHub

Tags: android, android-studio, github, build-automation

I have an Android project hosted on GitHub. Is there some way I can build this project and generate an (unsigned) APK file, every time code is pushed to the repository?

Or maybe once a day?

I don't really have any tests for it right now, so that's alright.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use **[Jenkins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenkins_%28software%29)**.

**And thing which you are trying to do can be solved by referring to *[Building Gradle Projects with Jenkins CI](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Building-Gradle-Projects-with-Jenkins-CI)*.

Other than Jenkins there are also some others:

- [Circle](https://circleci.com/)
- [Travis](https://travis-ci.org/)

Comment: You can also try https://www.bitrise.io - it's more tuned for mobile apps than Circle or Travis is. For your case, it's simply enough the follow the setup guide, and you'll get a configuration which will generate the APK and attaches it to the build.

Answer (score -1):

You might find [Jenkins](https://jenkins-ci.org/) a helpful assistant.